# How do I make Boost build for i386 on OS X 64 bit?

Tags: macos, boost, build, osx-snow-leopard, 32-bit

I've been battling with Boost to make it compile as only 32 bit than 64 bit on a 64 bit OS X host.

Is there an easy edit I can make to the darwin-specific bjam config file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
bjam toolset=darwin address-model=32
```

Comment: To anyone depending upon this as the answer: I needed to follow the other answer's indication to include, in addition, `architecture=x86` in order to successfully build Boost as 32-bit on a 64-bit OSX 10.6 system.

Answer (score 9):

For i386 specifically, I'd try:

> bjam toolset=darwin architecture=x86 address-model=32

Comment: This answer worked for me.  (The `architecture=x86` was also required for me.)